# Moving data between sheets with arrayformulas in headers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm moving rows between sheets in Google Sheets using a simple AppScript. It works great, however when I apply ArrayFormulas to several of the header columns in the workbook then the ArrayFormula fails as the values have been copied between the cells as I now have static data in several of the cells, thus preventing the ArrayFormula from fully copying down.

I tried clearing the ranges after the rows have been moved but it seems very inefficient and does not seem to work on occasions.

Any advice to revise my script would be appreciated.

```
function moveRows(e) {
  let r = e.range;
  
  if (r.columnStart != 2 || r.rowStart == 2 || e.value == null) return;

  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const valArray = ["Estimate","Sold","Service"];
  const destArray = ["Estimates","Sold Installs","Service Log"];
  
  let dest = sh.getSheetByName(destArray[valArray.indexOf(e.value)]);
  let src = sh.getActiveSheet();
  let estsheet = sh.getSheetByName("Estimates");
  let soldsheet = sh.getSheetByName("Sold Installs");
  let sersheet = sh.getSheetByName("Service Log");
  
  if (dest.getName() == src.getName()) return;

   /* getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) */

  src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,65).moveTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,65));
  src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);

/* code to delete values in columns that use ArrayFormulas */

  estsheet.getRange('G3:G').clearContent(),
  estsheet.getRange('Z3:Z').clearContent(),
  estsheet.getRange('AQ3:AQ').clearContent(),
  estsheet.getRange('AT3:AX').clearContent(),
  estsheet.getRange('BB3:BB').clearContent(),
  estsheet.getRange('BK3:BK').clearContent();

  soldsheet.getRange('G3:G').clearContent(),
  soldsheet.getRange('Z3:Z').clearContent(),
  soldsheet.getRange('AQ3:AQ').clearContent(),
  soldsheet.getRange('AT3:AX').clearContent(),
  soldsheet.getRange('BB3:BB').clearContent(),
  soldsheet.getRange('BK3:BK').clearContent();

  sersheet.getRange('G3:G').clearContent(),
  sersheet.getRange('Z3:Z').clearContent(),
  sersheet.getRange('AQ3:AQ').clearContent(),
  sersheet.getRange('AT3:AX').clearContent(),
  sersheet.getRange('BB3:BB').clearContent(),
  sersheet.getRange('BK3:BK').clearContent();

}
```

You can see an example of the arrayformula populating Col BB below:

[image: Arrayformula in use in Col BB]

Comment: Why does it not work on all ocasions? Consider clearing the range before applying an overflowing array formula. A test destination spreadhseet and the exact formula would help to udnerstand the issue.

Comment: It seems to me that clearing the range prior to rows being copied would result in the data being populated by the arrayformula first which isn't my intention here. I'm happy to try if you think I'm missing something.

Comment: I've added a screenshot to my post to give an example of one of the arrayformulas.